# WCF Error With Third Party DLL

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to `WCF` and facing some issue. I have three project `WCFClient`,`WCFService`,`CommonModel`

1. `CommonModel` :- Have below classes 

   `public class Room: INotifyPropertyChanged
           {
               int roomID;
               public virtual int roomID_PK { get; set; }
               public Room()
                   {
                        Row1Details = new RoomRowDetails();
                        Row2Details = new RoomRowDetails();
                   } 
            }`

   [Serializable]
       public class RoomRowDetails : ISerializable, INotifyPropertyChanged
           {
           public RoomRowDetails()
               {
                   RoomColor = "White";
                   RowSaleAmount = "";
               }
   ....
       }
2. `WCFClient` : is having client proxy class.
3. `WCFService`: Have `ServiceContract` `OperationContract` `DataContract` and have  below class :-

   ```
   [DataContract()]
   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Room))]
   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(RoomRowDetails))]
   public class RequestData
       {

       [DataMember]
       public string ClientName { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public bool isServer { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public bool isSuccess { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public Room room { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public RoomRowDetails roomrow{ get; set; }
       }
   ```

In both the project `CommandModel` project is added as a reference. Client proxy is generated properly but when run the project. I got below error:-

`There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:eventData. The InnerException message was 'Type 'CommonModel.MODELS.Room' with data contract name 'Room:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CommonModel.MODELS' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.`

Can you please help me out how can i use `CommonModel` classes in `WCF` service and client (So Room is shared POCO between both the project) and avoid above error?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see `RoomRowDetails` or `Room` is a derived types of `RequestData`. Then why are you marking them with `ServiceKnownType` attribute?

Comment: there is no relationship between `RequestData` and `Room` i just tried  to run code with `ServiceKnownType`. But it did not worked.